# How to remove XML meta tags in java or jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp, replace, xml-parsing

i am having a xml something looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><content></content>
```

i just want to extract the content alone,i am expecting something like this.

```
<content></content>
```

i know String replace is a solution but it changes every time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
String extracted = Jsoup.parse(xml).getElementsByTag("s:body").first().html();
```